# How can I call the parent TableView to reload

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

In this iphone app I'm trying to make it so that when you select a table cell it saves that action, pops the current view controller and calls the previous view controller (which is and always will be a TableView) to reload it's cells with new data.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//update data code here
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
//Here is where I want the code to reload the view [parentTableView reload]; or something }
```

That's what I have at the moment when you select a cell in the current Table View

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need need to send `-reloadData` to the [*UITableView*](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

**Edit** : So just to clarify, you have a parent *UITableViewController* which pushes a child *UITableViewController* onto the *navigationController*?  The code in your sample is implemented in the *didSelectRowAtIndexPath* in the child view controller?

If this is the case, you need to to add a property to your child *UITableViewController* which stores a pointer to its parent.  Make sure this isn't a reference counted property because that will result in a circular reference.  So before you pop your child *UITableViewController* it can send `-reloadData` to the *tableView* property of its parent.

Comment: Thanks @NSResponder :).  Still not quite there with my Objective-C vernacular.

Comment: How would I get a reference to the previous tabelView though? I want the page you are going to to reload not the one you are leaving when you pop it off the navigation stack.

Comment: I solved it by passing a target and selector to the new view that works as a callback, also later on I was able to use a `NSNotification` to tell it to update when new data was avaliable